# Angularjs issue $http.get gives empty response

Tags: java, angularjs

How can I get the response when POSTs are from cross-site.
 I am new to angular JS.

I am trying to inject html which is not from the same context path using Angular JS.

It throws `empty 200 OK` which triggers an error function instead of the success function.

How can I inject html ?

Comment: add more info of question.

Comment: Look at the error parameter of the error function. It would contain the cause of error. Maybe deserialization error.